# Java Inheritance not working

Tags: java, class, oop, object, inheritance

I have three classes: A, B, Main. Class Main extends class A and B extends Main.

A

```
class A{

    ArrayList<ABC> arr= new ArrayList<>();

    void addData(){
        a();
    }

    void add(){
        ABC abc1 = new ABC("qwer", "qwer", "qwer", 4, 1, "qweqw", "qweqwe");
        ABC abc2 = new ABC("qwer", "qwer", "qwer", 4, 1, "qweqw", "qweqwe");
        arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(abc1,abc2));
    }
}
```

MAIN

```
class Main extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        A a = new A();
        a.add();
        B b = new B();
        b.choose();
    }
}
```

B

```
class B extends Main{
    Main m = new Main();
    void choose() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(m.arr.size());
    }
}
```

But extends doesn't seem to work on class B. When checking the array size on class B, it returns 0 instead of the 2 entries that was added on Main.

Did I misunderstood how inheritance works or is there something wrong with the code itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Main m = new Main();
```

This code in `class B` will simply create an object of `Main class`.  After this you need to call this to  fill the `arrayList`.

```
   m.add()
```

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted your answer since it helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two instances, one of class `A` and one of class `B`. And when creating an instance of `B`, you also create another instance of `Main`, as an instance variable of `B` (`Main m = new Main();`).

Then you call `add` only for the first instance (`a.add()`), so the `List` accessed by the call to `b.choose()`, which is the `List` of the `Main` instance (since you call `m.arr.size()`) is empty.

This has nothing to do with "how inheritance works". It has to do with instance variables, such as your `ArrayList<ABC> arr` containing different values for different instances (objects) of your classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining what was wrong! :)